# PC Overheating at idle (Confusing)

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

Let me start out by saying that this system is a non-OC'd system with a stock cooler.

So i kept getting BSOD's yesterday while gaming. So i checked out the cpu temp is CoreTemp and it is reporting 100C (obv way too high).

I checked the temp in bios and it was reporting 60-70C.

I then checked with SpeedFan and it reports 73C.

Regardless, i removed the heatsink and cleaned it out and re-applied thermal compound.

CoreTemp still reports 100C and SpeedFan still reports 73C. Any ideas are appreciated.

[image: CPU Temps]

Comment: What thermal solution are you using?

Comment: Are your cooler stands firm over processor? (is it has good contatct and is not wobbly)

Check your fan speed, is it okay? check fan speed settings in bios also.

Comment: Not wobbly at all, fan speed settings set to "turbo" in bios. You can see the fan speed in the screenshot.

Comment: Thermal Solution? like what thermal compound? or what cooler?

Comment: The cooler attached to the system.

Comment: Cooler is a stock intel cooler as stated in the initial post.

Comment: your fans are either dying or are completely unresponsive to the rise in temps. CPU fans (80mm and under) are generally above 3000RPM when the CPU temp is high, and case fans (120mm) are capable of 2000RPM, so they are either damaged, or dialed down for some reason. Have you used any advanced bios or motherboard software to adjust your cooling profile? when presented with "cool" or "quite" are you always selecting "cool"?

Comment: I always select "cool" and at the moment i have it on "turbo"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the CPU was improperly seated and/or thermal paste was improperly applied and the problem can no longer be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

I learned it was an Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver  that was causing my problem with Monitor off/high fan noise while idle.  Doesn't seem logical but it solved the problem. If your computer is running as Windows 10 with Intel chips, suggest two things:

A. Reinstall any rapid storage technology drivers from your computer manufacturer's website.  (Not Intel's update which may put in drivers incompatible with your system-even though its intel based).

B. THEN, if that doesn't work, actually  run Intel update from their website, install the Driver update support assistant from here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html and install what it suggests and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I re-seated the CPU and it seems to be fixed now.